# Error when using CopyTo command with BitArrays

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview, bitarray

Starters:  Here is the error that gets generated:

**Destination array was not long enough. Check destIndex and length, and the array's lower bounds.**

Code: C#, ASP.NET

Env: VS 2005

What I'm doing is using a BitArray to flip bits based on a certain condition of a TreeView.  Right now I'm traversing a TreeView and if the node is checked from a child, I will flip an index in the BitArray.  I have multiple TreeViews that I am traversing so I have multiple BitArrays.  Once I get all the BitArrays populated, I will convert the bits to an integer value (encoded in a sense) and place them in an int array.  Then the ultimate goal is to push the integer values to a database but obviously I can't get that far.  Sample code provided below:

```
        BitArray MTRTECH = new BitArray(8);
        BitArray MTRRD = new BitArray(200);
        BitArray REVSE = new BitArray(100);
        BitArray ETXA = new BitArray(100);
        int[] conversion = new int[11];


        ParentChildCheck(MTRTECHTreeView, MTRTECH);
        MTRTECH.CopyTo(conversion, 7);
        ParentChildCheck(MTRRDRTreeView, MTRRD);
        MTRRD.CopyTo(conversion, 8);  <================ Throws Error Here
        ParentChildCheck(REVSECTreeView, REVSE);
        REVSE.CopyTo(conversion, 9); 
        ParentChildCheck(EXTRATreeView, ETXA);
        ETXA.CopyTo(conversion, 10);



    protected void ParentChildCheck(TreeView parent, BitArray Changes)
    {
        TreeNode temp = new TreeNode();

        for (int index = 0; index < parent.Nodes.Count; index++)
        {
            temp = parent.Nodes[index];

            for (int index2 = 0; index2 < temp.ChildNodes.Count; index2++)
            {
                ChildCheck(temp.ChildNodes[index2],Changes,index2);
            }
        }

    }

    protected void ChildCheck(TreeNode node, BitArray Selection, int value)
    {
        message2 += node.Text;
        Selection.Set(value, true);
        counter++;

        for (int index = 0; index < node.ChildNodes.Count; index++)
        {
            value++;
            ChildCheck(node.ChildNodes[index],Selection,value);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your source `BitArray` MTRRD is internally stored as an array of 7 `Int32s`, your destination array `conversion` is an array of 11 `Int32s`. When you perform the copy you are specifying a index of 8, this index is an index into the destination array, so the copy will overrun because your desintation is not long enough to contain all 7 `Int32s` starting at index 8.

Comment: Thanks.  After beating my head against a wall for 2 hours I posted .. then figured out right after the post that I'm an idiot.  Fixed it.  went to delete it and I saw that you answered.